# Cannot get associated photo to status message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a Rails 3.2.6 app and I have a question about association.
I am using Transloadit to upload and process images and when the processing is done
I get an assembly_id which I save in both the Photo model as well as in a Status model.

1. A Status has_one photo.
2. A Photo belongs to a Status.

*So this is the setup.*

1. An Event can have many status messages
2. A status message belongs to an event and can have one photo

Normally I would enter status_id into the Photo but I have replaced this by saving the
assembly id into the Status object instead.

I know I can get the image like this:

```
p = Photo.find_by_assembly_id (s.assembly_id)
```

But I need to be able to do this and get the photo too (and not just the status data):

```
@event.statuses
```

Perhaps like this

```
@event.statuses.includes(:photo)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a has_one :photo relationship to the Status model?  So the photo for the first status of the event would be @event.statuses.first.photo

Comment: Yes. But I need to get all statuses with attached photos for each. Preferrably with one query.

Answer (score 0):

try to use like
`@event = Event.find(params[:id]).includes(:status => :photo)`
 
# or .includes(:statuses => :photos)`